# Why does God instruct Moses to tell Pharaoh that they are going into the wilderness for three days in Exodus 3:18?

Tags: exodus, moses

Exodus 3:18 NASB

> 18 They will [l]pay heed to what you say; and you with the elders of Israel will come to the king of Egypt and you will say to him, ‘The Lord, the God of the Hebrews, has met with us. ***So now, please, let us go a three days’ journey into the wilderness, that we may sacrifice to the Lord our God***.’

Its clear God had already revealed to Moses that they were leaving Egypt for ever

Why then instruct him to tell Pharaoh that they were going for three days into the wilderness to worship

Was God placating Pharaoh?

Answer (score 3):

**Why does God instruct Moses to tell Pharaoh that they are going into the wilderness for three days in Exodus 3:18?**

Exodus 3:18 NASB

> 18 They will [l]pay heed to what you say; and you with the elders of
>   Israel will come to the king of Egypt and you will say to him, ‘The
>   Lord, the God of the Hebrews, has met with us. So now, please, let us
>   go a three days’ journey into the wilderness, that we may sacrifice to
>   the Lord our God.’

**Was God placating Pharaoh?, No ,God was not placating Pharaoh, He was testing Pharaoh's heart, by means of this reasonable request, it revealed what was in Pharaoh's heart- his heart was hard.**

Leaving Egypt for just three days would have been of little loss to the Egyptians, however if Moses and Aaron indicated that God purposed  that the Israelites were to leave Egypt permanently , it was most likely that Pharaoh would have raised objections, just imagine if over one million people were to pack up and leave permanently overnight. The Israelites were slaves to the Egyptians , minding their fields , livestock ,buildings and other.

Pharaoh not only objected to the Israelites leaving for just  three days , he further decreed  harsher  labors on them:

Exodus 5:6-9  (NASB)

Israel’s Labor Increased

> 6 "So the same day Pharaoh commanded the taskmasters over the people
>   and their foremen, saying, 7 “You are no longer to give the people
>   straw to make brick as previously; let them go and gather straw for
>   themselves. 8 But the quota of bricks which they were making
>   previously, you shall impose on them; you are not to reduce any of it.
>   Because they are lazy, therefore they cry out, Let us go and sacrifice
>   to our God.’ 9 Let the labor be heavier on the men, and let them work
>   at it so that they will pay no attention to false words.”

Answer (score 1):

Let us go a three-days journey into the wilderness.

It was a measurement of distance to the location of sacrifice. The full duration of absence was not mentioned by Moses. But Pharaoh understood that if he let them go, they would not return.

As step-1, God instructed Moses to make this initial demand on Pharaoh and already it got no where. This was just God's step by step work on Pharaoh and on Egypt.